# Php delete data from sqlite3 from select(from database) option in HTML

Tags: php, html, sqlite

```
<div><select class="form-control"name="old_name"></select></div>
<div><input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" pattern="^[\w\- ]+$"/></div>
```

Noted that all items in select tag is generated from a javascript using "innerHTML" to update information from database.

There are two elements(old_name, name) in HTML form which using POST method. I want to replace "old_name" with "name" with php. Here is my Php Code.

```
$orignal_name = $_POST['old_name'];
$q = $db->prepare("UPDATE categories SET name = ? WHERE name = ". $orignal_name);
return $q->execute(array($_POST['name']));
```

But it did not work. I try to echo "old_name" and the result is "NaN".

Comment: Why use a parameter for one `name` and concatentate a value onto the second???

Comment: because the parameter ? is the input in HTML. Set it as parameter can prevent Injection. While the second value is fixed with select tag.

Comment: POSTED data can be spoofed, quite easily. Dont assume the data coming into any script from GET or POST is safe

Comment: Also I can edit what is in a `<option>` tag very easily before submitting a form with almost any browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual error is that you did not wrap the `$original_name` concatenation in quotes, but this would be a better approach

```
$q = $db->prepare("UPDATE categories SET name = ? WHERE name = ?");

return $q->execute(array($_POST['name'], $_POST['old_name']));
```

> I assume you are checking that both these occurances exist in `$_POST` and contain data before getting to this code.

Comment: I have a AJAX error after I add one more parameter. I am checking where is the error and decided whether accept the solution. Thanks for your help

Comment: OK, but your question has nothing to do with AJAX as it is asked

Comment: Actually looking at the HTML you show, the `<select>` tag does not appear to have an `<option>` tags inside it. Is that because you just shortened the code or missed that completely

Comment: all option is generated from a javescript.

Comment: something like xxxx.innerHTML = '<option></option>' + options.join('');

Comment: Ah ok, yes I remember you said that now